# More info on tzerufei shemos (permutations of G-d's name) vis-a-vis months of the year?

Tags: calendar, tefilla, prayer-book, rosh-chodesh-new-month, mysticism-kabbalah

I've seen some siddurim -- I think the Artscroll all-Hebrew Nusach Sefard -- that list one permutation of the name YKVK for each of the twelve months, and that one should have appropriate kavana when saying in musaf: Baruch ata HASHEM, mekadesh yisrael v'roshei chadashim.

(By the way, what about Tishrei?  Bakeseh l'yom chagenu, so we miss out on that permutational kavana?)

Can anyone recommend some reading on just the basics of how the months correspond to the permutations, and/or the other verses and such listed in some siddurs' charts?

Answer (score 1):

Bnei Yissochar would be Your basic Text.But I highly recomend Rabbi Aryeh Kaplans stuff I do not remember where but he covers it somewhere in his collected writings I think. also a good source  would be This book

[THE WISDOM IN THE HEBREW MONTHS](http://www.artscroll.com/Books/whmh.html)

Comment: I would Imagine Mekubal could this this question way more Justice than me so I suggest you wait for his answer

Answer (score 0):

Sefer Yesira would be your primary source. However, I think I remember seeing it in an Arizal Siddur.